# Convert string to 2 decimal Number in 1 line

Tags: javascript, numbers, rounding

I have a string 123.4567 that I want to convert to a Number with two decimals and I want to do this in 1 short line in Javascript.

```js
const x = "123.4567";

// this works but seems way too cumbersome
const y = parseFloat((parseFloat(x)).toFixed(2))
console.log(typeof(y) + " / " + y)      //Prints: number / 123.45

// this I expected to work but it doesn't
const z = (parseFloat(x)).toFixed(2)
console.log(typeof(z) + " / " + z)      //Prints: string / 123.45
```

Comment: Both log the same thing...

Comment: some thing is wrong in your question : both returns `number / 123.46`

Comment: I can't duplicate that. I get "number / 123.46" for that second example as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I've reformatted the code snippet.

Comment: Numbers don't _have_ fixed numbers of decimals. That's why `toFixed()` returns strings. Try with `const x = "3.0000"`, for example, where the first version will print `number / 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that :

```js
const
  x = "123.4567" 
, y = (0 | (parseFloat(x) *100)) /100 // or (0|parseFloat(x) *100) /100 - see JS Operator precedence
, z = +(+x).toFixed(2)                // use + for type cast number
, w = +(0 || x.match(/\d*\.?\d{0,2}/)[0])  // best regex i can do...
  ;


console.log(`${typeof y} / ${y}`)  // number / 123.45
console.log(`${typeof z} / ${z}`)  // number / 123.46  the same + 0.01 (rounding)
console.log(`${typeof w} / ${w}`)  // number / 123.45
```

Nb: `( 0 | number )` return integer part of any floating number (`|` = bynary OR operator)